# Find the area between the positive branch of the ellipse using left end point, right end point, upper sum and lower sum approximations

Tags: calculus

My homework asks for this basically:

Find the area between the positive branch of the ellipse (x/2)^2+y^2=1 using left end point, right end point, upper sum and lower sum approximations with n=8 points.

Maybe I'm just too dumb but I couldn't find a reliable source on the web to do this, also I didn't pay attention to the class much, but I think I'm supposed to find a delta x, but how am I supposed to find it without having b and a given? What I wrote above is literally the question. So there's no other information.

Comment: Hint: set $y(x) = \sqrt{ \ldots }$ and look up numeric integration of a function

Comment: Yeah I actually did that, but I'm still stuck with the delta x thing.

Comment: If $a$ is the domain of $x$, when split into $n$ points then $\Delta x = \frac{a}{n}$. Don't overthink it!

Comment: See rectangular method in [this pdf lecture notes](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~dlevy/classes/amsc466/lecture-notes/integration-chap.pdf)